# db.collection.find returns multiple records after addToSet

Tags: mongodb, updates

I use `addToSet` command (to add `UpdatedData`):

```
MyTable.update({ "UrlLink": "http://www.someurl.com"}, {
        $addToSet: {
            UpdatedData: {
                TheDate: ThisDate,
                NewInfo: ThisInfo
            }
        }
    },
        function (err, result) {
                next(err,result)
        }
);
```

But then, when I do the query (after `UpdatedData` is added to my document), I see that it returns two documents. Instead of only one updated `document`:

```
db.MyTable.find( {"UrlLink": "http://www.someurl.com"})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56485922143a886f66c2f8bb"), "UrlLink" : "http://www.someurl.com", "Stuff" : "One", "UpdatedData" : [ { "TheDate" : "11/15/2015", "NewInfo" : "Info1", "_id" : ObjectId("5648599a71efc79c660f76d3") } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5648599f71efc79c660f76d4"), "UrlLink" : "http://www.someurl.com", "Stuff": "One", "UpdatedData" : [ ] }
```

So it seems that `addToSet` creates a new document with new `_id`, instead of updating the old record (`ObjectId("5648599f71efc79c660f76d4")`). But I only see the updated document in `robomongo` (`ObjectId("56485922143a886f66c2f8bb")`). Any ideas why this happens and how I could prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` cannot create a new document, it can only `update` existing. 
This looks like you have created two documents with the same url.. Then when you update it just updates the first one..

To prevent the creation of a document with an already existent url you can create an index and set it to unique

`db.collection.createIndex({ UrlLink: 1 }, { unique: true })`

This will prevent creation of new documents with the same url, and it will also make queries by **UrlLink** as fast as possible.

Comment: Ok but I only see the updated in robomongo, It is strange that query returns two documents?

Comment: @user1665355 Which mongodb driver are you using? which mongodb version?

Comment: 3.0 version. I will try your solution

Comment: @user1665355 Take attention that robomongo does not support 3.0.. so dont rely on robomongo output.. Instead test your queries directly in the cli..

Comment: Ok, installed 3.0 because it works with Meteor. "in the cli", you mean in terminal?

Comment: @user1665355 Ok, this means this is a meteor project? Yes, in the cli means terminal.. cli = command line interface.. You can open the mongo cli by typing $ meteor mongo (from the project dir)

Comment: I am just learning meteor and mongo:) so basically you think that without createIndex I do get duplicates after updating?

Comment: @user1665355 I am sure, that you have created multiple docs with the same UrlLink